# running the same database both local and online in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, mirroring

I am creating a software for my client in PHP and MySql, The software will be running in the local network, the software should also run in online that is all the data should be viewed online, i would like to know is there a way to update the mysql database from local to online whenever the internet is connected, if the internet is not connected all the data will be stored in local mysql server. they wont be adding any data in the online server and they will only view the contents. Kindly help me in this

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to have a read-only, "online" (assuming WAN) MySQL server which is updated from a read-write, "offline" (LAN) MySQL Server which is updated by your users.

If that's the case, you may want to consider a Master/Slave MySQL Replication configuration:
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-replication-masterslave

Answer (score 0):

you can run a cron job in your local server which monitor and upload data to online server when internet is available. You need to track (set a status) which data is uploaded which not for synchronization

Comment: "you can run a **corn** job" ... gets my vote for typo of the week :)

Comment: Thanks for the info but now i am facing a new problem, My client is running a whole sale and retail automobile store and he is buying products from suppliers and selling it out to everyone, he has a very huge store so he cant give internet to all systems. so he asked for a local server to store all datas in that server and when the internet is connected these datas will be uploaded to the online server, so when he goes out for purchase he can check the inventory from where ever he want. But he is asking me to give him a solution where he will add stock from where ever he wants

Comment: and the  stock should update in the local system also, as i am very new to php and my sql i have no idea how to achieve this. we may have update from both sides local and online , kindly help me in this

Comment: One solution is to ensure local server always have internet connection. Alternatively do stock update only from online server

Answer (score 0):

Setup replication between your mysql databases. The local network database would be the slave and the web server would be the master.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html for setting up replication.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you setup master/slave replication.
I would make the local server the master and the internet server the slave.
However, if you are using a common shared hosting service, I am not too sure if you have permission to setup such DB replication structure.

Tryhttps://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql. However, with the mysql versions pre 5.6 (I think) you can't delay the replication from a predefined interval. However, http://alexalexander.blogspot.com/2013/03/mysql-slave-delay-how-to.html suggests using something called a percona tool kit. I haven't used it though.